# How to setup cakePHP site on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp

Does anybody know how to get started hosting a cakePHP on Amazon Web Services, if that is even the correct service, or if it is even possible. I have seen a few articles that refer to being able to do this. AWS seems like a pretty full feature set, without a lot of guidance.

I am specifically would like to get Cake Baked on AWS with Amazon RDS. Just getting the default dite up and running would be enough.

I have seen these links as well as a few others, but I haven't found any basic how-to information.

https://github.com/joebeeson/amazon

[Hosting CakePHP app with Amazon Web Services (EC2, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395318/hosting-cakephp-app-with-amazon-web-services-ec2-etc)

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works -- I have several cakephp sites on AWS.  I will warn you there are a lot of annoying little bugs and hurdles with AWS though.

You'll need to understand two things -- how to use AWS and how to configure a server from scratch.  If you've never configured a server from zero, I'd highly recommend going with another host.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying tht you need to install installing linux on up, or just apache, php, mysql, etc.?

I have setup a server from scratch, but I am curious about the annoying little bugs. How much of a time suck are they?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated I don't know any how-to guide on exactly that, and it is basically because any server that can run PHP 5.3 with mod_rewrite works great. I recommend you to follow any tutorial to get a server on Amazon AWS and then just download cake on the server with wget.